# can I generate listenKey binance in app script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, websocket, binance

I try a lot of think to create listenKey in app script but nothing work.
the binance URL: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#user-data-streams

this is my code:

```
function generated_key() {

  var aPIKEY = '*****'; // key.
  var secretKey = '****'; // Secret key.

  var api = "/api/v3/userDataStream";
  var timestamp = Number(new Date().getTime()).toFixed(0);
  var string = "timestamp="+timestamp;

  var baseUrl = "https://api1.binance.com";
  var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(string, secretKey);
    signature = signature.map(function(e) {
        var v = (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16);
        return v.length == 1 ? "0" + v : v;
  }).join("");
  var query = "?" + string + "&signature=" + signature;
  var params = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': {'X-MBX-APIKEY': aPIKEY},
        'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + api + query, params);
  var obj = JSON.parse(data); // To JSON
  Logger.log(obj)
}
```

I get the result error: `{code=-1101.0, msg=Too many parameters; expected '0' and received '2'.}`
any suggestion to do it.

Comment: About `I try a lot of think to create listenKey in app script but nothing work.`, can you add your script to your question?

Comment: @Tanaike I add my code above you can see it now.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. When I saw your provided document, at "Create a ListenKey (USER_STREAM)" section, it seems that `Parameters:` is `NONE`. So, when `baseUrl + api + query` is modified to `baseUrl + api`, what result will you obtain? Unfortunately, I cannot test this. I apologize for this.

Comment: the method need to put keys. I try it to see as you want the error: `Exception: Request failed for https://api1.binance.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: <html><body><h2>404 Not found</h2></body></html> (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.